# Big-Theta(n^m) recursive

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

I'm trying to implement an algorithm with time complexity in Big-Theta(n^m), n and m are natural numbers.

My first solution:

```
algo(n,m,i){ // called with algo(n,m,1)
  if (i < m){
   algo(n,m,i+1)
  }
  for i = 1 to n{
    print(do something in constant time);
  }
}
```

My second solution:

```
algo(n,m,i){ //called with algo(n,m,m)
   if (i > 0){
      for j = 1 to n{
         algo(n,m,i-1)
      }
   }else{
   print(do something in constant time);
   }
}
```

When I analyze my second solution, called `algo(n,m,m)`, I get `T(i) = n * T(i-1), i > 0`.
With T(0) = constant time I get `T(i) = n^m`. So I think my second solution is right, but I don't know what is wrong with my first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first algorithm,

```
if (i < m)
    algo(n, m, i+1)
```

will basically call `algo` for total of `m * (m-1) / 2` times, each `algo` has a `O(n)` loop, so, the total complexity will be `O(n * m ^ 2)`.

Or in other words, for the first algorithm, it's similar to `T(i) = n + T(i-1)`, where `i = 0, ..., m`.

Comment: Isn't the term for the first algorithm T(i) = n + T(i-1)?